# Azure easy tables - PUT not working

Tags: php, azure, azure-api-apps

I'm using the Rest Api to Post, Get and Put into my easy tables using PHP. While POST and GET works, I cannot get PUT to work.

Here is my code:

```
$urlAzure = 'https://<account name>.azurewebsites.net/tables/<tableName>(PartitionKey="<key>",RowKey="<row key>")';

  $dataAzure = array (
  'PartitionKey' => <key>,
  'Owner' => $_SESSION['username'],
  'RowKey' => '<row key>',
  'mediaUrl' => ''
  );


  $optionsAzure = array(
    'http' => array(
      'method'  => 'PUT',
      'content' => json_encode( $dataAzure ),
      'header'=>  "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
                "Accept: application/json\r\n"
    )
  );
  $contextAzure  = stream_context_create($optionsAzure);
  $resultAzure= file_get_contents($urlAzure, false, $contextAzure);
  if ($resultAzure === FALSE) {}
```

Unfortunately, this is not working. After the whole day of trial, I have managed to get the following errors :

- HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.
- and sometimes : The item does not exist

(this depends on whether I make a space or not in the url. Of course, the item is in my table).

I am really stuck. Does anyone have an idea why it is not working  ?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answer Gary Liu and for the link. In fact, the PUT method in this case is done using PATCH. So, thanks to you, here is what I got :)

```
$urlAzure = 'https://<myAccountName>.azurewebsites.net/tables/<myTable>/<id>;
$dataAzure = array (
 <my array to 'PATCH'>
);
$optionsAzure = array(
 'http' => array(
    'method'  => 'PATCH',
    'content' => json_encode( $dataAzure ),
          'header'=>  "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
                    "Accept: application/json\r\n"
    )
);
$contextAzure  = stream_context_create($optionsAzure);
$resultAzure= file_get_contents($urlAzure, false, $contextAzure);
if ($resultAzure === FALSE) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are implementing table operations in Easy Tables in Mobile Apps. If I have any misunderstanding, please feel free to let me know.

As the azure-mobile-apps Node.js Server SDK provides mechanisms to expose data tables stored in Azure SQL Database as a WebAPI, but it doesn't expose the `PUT` method. You can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-node-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/#TableOperations for more info.

If you insist on implementing with `PUT` method, you can generate a custom API leveraging Easy APIs.